# How to mock RestTemplate with Client or Server errors?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, resttemplate

I'm using a `restTemplate.postForEntity()` in my code.
When testing the class around it, I use Mockito to mock RestTemplate.

`Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(.....)).thenReturn(response)`

where response is:

`ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);`

Now, when I run this test, the `postForEntity` returns the mock response I just showed. However, in real executions, the RestTemplate throws a `RestClientException` when it receives a `401` from the remote.

Under the hood this is because `doExecute()` in `RestTemplate` checks for errors and throws an this exception in case of 4XX and 5XX errors.

I can of course rewrite the mock rule:

`Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(.....)).thenThrow(new RestClientException(..))`.

But in when reading the test this is not very intuitive: I would like it to response to a 401 or a 500 itself.

What should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: The way to go is `thenThrow(new RestClientException(..)` if you mock the `RestTemplate` (note that you could also use a real RestTemplate and [mock the Http server](https://www.google.com/search?q=mock+http+server))

Answer (score 3):

You already said it in your question: you are mocking RestTemplate and testing a class that makes use of it. You are not stubbing it, just mocking.

If you wanted RestTemplate to throw that exception based on a http status it receives, then you would need to mock the internal client RestTemplate uses and make it return that status code when it is called. Then your RestTemplate should be stubbed (or use real implementation) to react to that http status.

But it seems to me this is not what you want to test.

If you are talking only about readability of the test (but keep testing what you are testing), then i would suggest to create a method that generates a mockito Answer based on a http status. if the status is not 200 then the answer should throw an exception.

So, in your resttemplate mock you would have:

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(...))
    .thenAnswer(answer(401));
```

and answer implementation something like:

```
private Answer answer(int httpStatus) {
    return (invocation) -> {
        if (httpStatus >= 400) {
            throw new RestClientException(...);
        }
        return <whatever>;
    };
}
```

this is just an example, you would need to adapt to your specific needs.

Comment: I would probably take a step further and base the answer of the `DefaultErrorDecoder` that the RestTemplate uses to ensure you are handling the expected exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Spring built-in test library, like here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html

That way you mock an endpoint you call

Answer (score 1):

we can mock like this, this will return HttpClientErrorException with error code 401.

```
  when(restTemplate.postForEntity(url,new HttpEntity<>. 
         (authHeader()),String.class))
       .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus. UNAUTHORIZED));
```